# R Plot Specify number of time tickmarks - time/date equivalent to pretty

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering how I could plot more tick marks when plotting time on the x-axis.

Basically, a time equivalent to pretty. Pretty obviously doesn't work so well with times, as it uses factors of 1,2,5 and 10. For time one probably wants e.g. hours, half hours, ...

```
plot(as.POSIXct(x,origin="1960-01-01"),y,type="l",xlab="Time")
```

gives really too few and widely spaced tickmarks.

```
zoox<-zoo(y,as.POSIXct(stats$Time,origin="1960-01-01"))
plot(zoox)
```

gives the same.

Thanks

EDIT:

Just to clarify (so far answers don't address my issue): What I am looking for is a function like pretty for dates, e.g. a function, that takes a start date, an end date, a number of ticks, and outputs the location of the ticks. That is, I am well aware it is possible to plot hours, to plot minutes, and what else, but pretty automates the tick distance for numbers, and a resulting function for dates should decide by itself whether to use days, hours, minutes, second, milliseconds, microseconds, 30 minutes, 500 micros, 5 seconds, etc. intervals. That is what pretty does for numbers, anyway.

EDIT2:

This is the function I currently use to decide the format for the time axis (note that this doesn't work for dates):

```
mydiff <- end-start
if(mydiff>1800) {
    axis.POSIXct(1,xrange,format="%H:%M")
} else if(mydiff>30) {
    axis.POSIXct(1,xrange,format="%H:%M:%S")
} else if(mydiff>0.5) {
    axis.POSIXct(1,xrange,format="%H:%M:%OS3")
} else
    axis.POSIXct(1,xrange,format="%H:%M:%OS6")
}
```

I don't have a function that increase tick marks, so I use the default number of tick marks

Comment: R's internal functions will not consider time units lower than the second. The `POSIXct` class can deal with decimal seconds, but the helper functions around this class generally only work at the second level. So the microsecond interval will really be in decimal seconds **and** have to be handled by hand.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: Untrue, at least on my system micros work perfectly. Use `axis.POSIXct(1,xrange,format="%H:%M:%OS6")` to display them in the chart. Let me make another edit with an appropriate function. While the unit is seconds, it is a double value, and has quite high precision.

Comment: Does `library(xts); ?axTicksByTime`, or `quantmod:::axTicksByTime2` do what you want?

Comment: @Cookie Sorry, I didn't really express that one clearly. What I meant was you can't do `by = "500 microseconds"`; R only understands decimal seconds *and* has automatic handling in `seq()`, `axis.POSIXt()` etc at the seconds level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`axis.POSIXct()` already works quite hard to guess suitable pretty values for the axis, so I would start by hacking that. At the moment, it relies internally on using `pretty()` applied to the some function of the datetimes. It uses the defaults for `pretty()` so you could hack the function to add an `n` or `min.n` argument which would increase the number of pretty marks selected.

Copy `axis.POSIXct()` to your own function/file (give it a new name). Add a `n` or `min.n` argument to the definition, probably with larger values as defaults than those used by the `pretty()` function. And pass that to each of the `pretty()` calls that is made.

Try it out. If it works reasonably well, then you can do `fixInNamespace(axis.POSIXct)` to make the same changes to the actual function so it gets used on all plots for which it is called.

P.S. Here is a possible hack

```
function (side, x, at, format, labels = TRUE, n = 5, ...) {
  mat <- missing(at) || is.null(at)
  if (!mat) 
    x <- as.POSIXct(at)
  else x <- as.POSIXct(x)
  range <- par("usr")[if (side%%2) 
    1L:2L
    else 3L:4L]
  d <- range[2L] - range[1L]
  z <- c(range, x[is.finite(x)])
  attr(z, "tzone") <- attr(x, "tzone")
  if (d < 1.1 ) {
    sc <- 0.001
    if (missing(format)) 
      format <- "%H:%M:%OS6"
  }
  else if (d < 1.1 * 30) {
    sc <- 1
    if (missing(format)) 
      format <- "%H:%M:%OS3"
  }
  else if (d < 1.1 * 60) {
    sc <- 1
    if (missing(format)) 
      format <- "%H:%M:%S"
  }
  else if (d < 1.1 * 30 * 60) {
    sc <- 60
    if (missing(format)) 
      format <- "%H:%M:%S"
  }
  else if (d < 1.1 * 60 * 60) {
    sc <- 60
    if (missing(format)) 
      format <- "%H:%M"
  }
  else if (d < 1.3 * 60 * 60 * 24) {
    sc <- 60 * 60
    if (missing(format)) 
      format <- "%H:%M"
  }
  else if (d < 2 * 60 * 60 * 24) {
    sc <- 60 * 60
    if (missing(format)) 
      format <- "%a %H:%M"
  }
  else if (d < 7 * 60 * 60 * 24) {
    sc <- 60 * 60 * 24
    if (missing(format)) 
      format <- "%a"
  }
  else {
    sc <- 60 * 60 * 24
  }
  if (d < 60 * 60 * 24 * 50) {
    zz <- pretty(z/sc,n=n)
    z <- zz * sc
    z <- .POSIXct(z, attr(x, "tzone"))
    if (sc == 60 * 60 * 24) 
      z <- as.POSIXct(round(z, "days"))
    if (missing(format)) 
      format <- "%b %d"
  }
  else if (d < 1.1 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365) {
    z <- .POSIXct(z, attr(x, "tzone"))
    zz <- as.POSIXlt(z)
    zz$mday <- zz$wday <- zz$yday <- 1
    zz$isdst <- -1
    zz$hour <- zz$min <- zz$sec <- 0
    zz$mon <- pretty(zz$mon,n=n)
    m <- length(zz$mon)
    M <- 2 * m
    m <- rep.int(zz$year[1L], m)
    zz$year <- c(m, m + 1)
    zz <- lapply(zz, function(x) rep(x, length.out = M))
    zz <- .POSIXlt(zz, attr(x, "tzone"))
    z <- as.POSIXct(zz)
    if (missing(format)) 
      format <- "%b"
  }
  else {
    z <- .POSIXct(z, attr(x, "tzone"))
    zz <- as.POSIXlt(z)
    zz$mday <- zz$wday <- zz$yday <- 1
    zz$isdst <- -1
    zz$mon <- zz$hour <- zz$min <- zz$sec <- 0
    zz$year <- pretty(zz$year,n=n)
    M <- length(zz$year)
    zz <- lapply(zz, function(x) rep(x, length.out = M))
    z <- as.POSIXct(.POSIXlt(zz))
    if (missing(format)) 
      format <- "%Y"
  }
  if (!mat) 
    z <- x[is.finite(x)]
  keep <- z >= range[1L] & z <= range[2L]
  z <- z[keep]
  if (!is.logical(labels)) 
    labels <- labels[keep]
  else if (identical(labels, TRUE)) 
    labels <- format(z, format = format)
  else if (identical(labels, FALSE)) 
    labels <- rep("", length(z))
  axis(side, at = z, labels = labels, ...)
}
```

Differences to the original function can be seen [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/89tc49wj)

Comment: Fair enough. Turns out to be quite simple, then, in the end - a function override would even help fix incorrect default display formats.

Comment: Well, yes, as long as you are happy with the way `pretty()` chooses things via factors 1,2,5 and 10. If that gets you close but you just need more ticks than default, hacking `axis.POSIXct` is the way to go. Or copy it into your own function, make the changes you want and use that instead in the code you show in Edit 2. Depends whether you want only plots via your zooming function to use the new heuristics or any plot produced by R.

Answer (score 10):

Using a reproducible example

```
set.seed(1)
x <- as.POSIXct(sort(sample(100000, 100)), origin="1960-01-01")
y <- rpois(100, 5)
plot(x, y, type = "l", xlab = "Time")
```

we can make use of the `axis.POSIXct()` function (one could also use the `Axis()` S3 generic as well) to add a custom axis to the plot. The main point here is that you, the user, are in full control of where ticks are draw and how they are labelled, you just need to work a little harder if the defaults don;t work for you.

First we plot the data but suppress drawing of the x-axis:

```
plot(x, y, type = "l", xlab = "Time", xaxt = "n")
```

Next I will add a major tick mark at the start of each hour. For this I create a sequence of datetimes that goes

1. **from** the rounded hour of the first observation in the series,
2. **to** the end of the last hour in which an observation was made (using `ceiling()` to move us on to the next hour),
3. **incrementing** the sequence in 1 hour (`by = "1 hour"`) units.

This sequence is supplied to the the `at` argument of `axis.POSIXct()`. The rest should be easy to follow if not read `?axis.POSIXct` and `?par`

```
## add axis tick at each hour:
axis.POSIXct(side = 1, x = x,
             at = seq(from = round(x[1], "hours"),
                      to = x[1] + ceiling(difftime(tail(x, 1), head(x, 1), 
                                                   units = "hours")),
                      by = "1 hour"),
             las = 2)
```

The resulting figure looks like this:

[image]

To show finer control, I now add minor tick marks at each half-hour location, but suppress the annotation of those ticks (via the `labels` argument) and also make the minor ticks shorter (via graphics parameter `tcl`). Notice how the `seq()` method's `by` argument can take a numeric amount of the stated interval

```
## add minor ticks at 30 min intervals to above plot
axis.POSIXct(side = 1, x = x,
             at = seq(from = round(x[1], "hours"),
                      to = x[1] + ceiling(difftime(tail(x, 1), head(x, 1), 
                                                   units = "hours")),
                       by = "30 mins"),
             las = 2, tcl = -0.2, labels = FALSE)
```

The plot now looks like this:

[image]

You can add your own labels rather than the ones that the `axis.POSIXct` function comes up with. If you want to do this, then we should assign the output from `seq()` to an object that we can then use the `format()` function on. For example:

```
plot(x, y, type = "l", xlab = "Time", xaxt = "n")
tseq <- seq(from = round(x[1], "hours"),
            to = x[1] + ceiling(difftime(tail(x, 1), head(x, 1), 
                                         units = "hours")),
            by = "1 hour")
axis.POSIXct(side = 1, x = x, at = tseq,
             labels = format(tseq, format = "%H:%M"), las = 2)
```

The resulting plot is shown below:

[image]

`format()` returns a character string of the formatted datetime. You can `paste()` on anything else you want or look at the other placeholders that can be used to format datetime objects in `?strftime`

Comment: Sorry for the effort that went into this answer, but you are still picking hours or half hours yourself. What would happen if there only were 10 seconds between start and end time? To give you an example, in my particular case I have an interactive plot - using `getGraphicsEvent()` - where I can zoom into the plot, and the further I zoom with the mouse, the plot axis slowly needs to switch from hours to minutes to seconds to milliseconds - and back, once I zoom back out.

Comment: I only chose those time intervals because you *explicitly* mentioned them. There is nothing in R canned that I am aware of that will do what you want so you'll need to combine the custom axis approach I show with a hacked version of `axis.POSIXct()`. See my other Answer for pointers on that. (Coming soon)

Comment: I am not disputing that it is possible to come up with a function in R (after all, R is just C and C++, and allows more third party plugins, so virtually anything is possible), all I am saying that so far, none is out there, and I haven't found the time to write one myself.

Comment: So another alternative would be to take your Edit 2 bit of code, but generate the sequence of datetimes as I show above, changing the `by` argument to a suitable value for each option in your if else clauses. I think you are pretty much there with the code you show plus the custom axis code I showed above. `axis.POSIXct()` does do quite a lot of what you want, the problem is that it uses `pretty()` with the defaults and you seem to want to vary them (have more ticks etc)? If so, try hacking `pretty()` as I mention below.

Comment: Thank you very much for this post.  I have POSIXct datetime objects (with times) and I tried `axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(min(x), max(x), by = "days"), format ="%b %d")` but that generates tick marks in the wrong positions! (I don't understand why.  It seems that the first tick mark is always flush left, even if the first data point is not at the start of a day.)  I also appreciate the minor tick marks code.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use function `axis.POSIXct` and/or function `cut.POSIXt`. Let's say your vector of date is `time` and your vector of value associated `x`:

```
plot(time,x,xaxt="n")
axis.POSIXct(side=1,at=seq(min(time),max(time),by="week"),format="%d-%m") #For instance
```

And, going further, with `cut.POSIXt`:

```
plot(time,x,xaxt="n")
axis.POSIXct(side=1,at=cut(time, breaks="week"),format="%d-%m")
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the defaults available for the axis in plot ( `axes = FALSE`, or individual axis)  and use the function axis to detail what you want for the axis (specifically the `at` argument).  see `?axis`

```
plot(cars, axes = FALSE)
axis( 1, at = c(5,6,7,10,11,12,21,22,23) )
```

Comment: Sorry to be more clear: Pretty computes tick marks. From a number of requested tickmarks. Or to rephrase the question to your example, where does that at vector of values come from?

Comment: @Cookie In my example, at is an arbitrary vector to show you can place the tick marks 'at' any location. Do I still misunderstand your question?  You could determine a different tick mark size and colour for quarter hours for example.

Comment: Yes you still misunderstand. Pretty tickmarks takes a random starting point, and a random end point, and a number of tickmarks, and comes up with pretty ones. What I need is a function that takes starttime,endtime,noOfTicks to and returns the at vector you cite above - ideally adjusting the time format as well.